How To get my github ci.yml gradle build to pass?
In my personal project that I am writing I am struggling to get the git build pipeline to work. Below is a link to the repo and failing run.
https://github.com/ashfrench/killer-sudoko/actions/runs/10636896423
actions/checkout@v4, actions/setup-java@v4, gradle/actions/setup-gradle@af1da67850ed9a4cedd57bfd976089dd991e2582, and actions/upload-artifact@v4 are not allowed to be used in ashfrench/killer-sudoko. Actions in this workflow must be: within a repository owned by ashfrench.

See https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26609. Seems like you have changed the default settings of your repository from Settings > Actions > Allow all actions and reusable workflows to your repo only.

So what would be the fix? What settings do I need to remove?

Revert to the default settings or choose more granular ones. See https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#managing-github-actions-permissions-for-your-repository for more details on it.

Thanks, I will revert and start again

I finally got my actions working.
Below is an example gist.github.com to test yourself
https://gist.github.com/ashfrench/4e29279b4d4755b8cd52a7aa1128b75d
